# How to scrape a JavaScript value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I’m new to PHP and coding in general and I can’t figure this out. I’m trying to get the number of kills from [this profile page](http://uberstrike.com/public_profile/631163).

At the moment, the string I am trying to get is:

```
29362
```

When I view the page source, this number is nowhere to be seen.

When I use inspect element, however, I find:

```
<td class="num">29362</td>
```

How can I get the content shown in inspect element instead of the content shown by viewing the page source?

Answer (score 2):

In using a tool like Firebug for Firefox, or the inspector for Safari and Chrome, you can see that at page load a series of AJAX requests are made for data. Though I didn't dig through all of the data returned by those requests, I do see the data you're looking for in at least one of them:

```
http://uberstrike.com/profile/all_stats/631163
```

So at page load JavaScript makes a series of AJAX requests back to the server to get all the data, then it manipulates the DOM to insert it all into the view.

If you wanted, your PHP could directly request the URL I pasted above and `json_decode` the response. This would produce a data structure for you to use which includes that number in the `kills_all_time` property.

Quick and dirty example:

```
<?php
$data_url = 'http://uberstrike.com/profile/all_stats/631163';

$serialized_data = file_get_contents($data_url);

$data = json_decode($serialized_data, true);

var_dump($data['kills_all_time']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the note and explanation of your actions.

Answer (score 0):

I looked and it looks like there is no API currently, so your best method will be to do an inter-web-server http request. Get the page you want and then it is a lot of string math from there.

I would recommend using string search to find `<td class="name">Kills</td>` and the kills row will appear right after it. From there its simply extracting the number using string math.

Comment: As he stated, the number does not appear in the outputted source, it is being inserted by JS after load. There is an API, which the JS is using. See my answer.

Comment: Yep, i didn't understand that from the wording, looked at it, looks like JSON, hopefully there isn't a lock on request origins.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what `JAAulde` has explained, it seems like there is a method to these AJAX requests.  And they are all based on the profile ID that can be found at the end of the URL:

```
http://uberstrike.com/public_profile/631163
```

Then in the Safari debugger (which is what I am using) you can see these XHR ([XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)) requests which are directly connected to API calls:

[image]

Then looking at the data in them shows some really nicely formatted JSON. Great! No scraping! So just go through these URLs to see what you can see:

```
http://uberstrike.com/profile/items

http://uberstrike.com/profile/user_info/631163

http://uberstrike.com/profile/user_loadout/631163

http://uberstrike.com/profile/all_stats/631163
```

And looking at the `all_stats` endpoint shows:

```
"kills_all_time":29362,
```

Nice!

So now let’s use some PHP `json_decode`ing like this:

```
// Set the URL to the data.
$url = 'http://uberstrike.com/profile/all_stats/631163';

// Get the contenst of the URL via file_get_contents.
$all_stats_json = file_get_contents($url);

// Decode the JSON string with the 'true' optionso we get any array.
$all_stats_json_decoded = json_decode($all_stats_json, true);

// Dump the results for testing.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($all_stats_json_decoded);
echo '</pre>';
```

Which will dump an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [headshots_record] => 24
    [nutshots_record] => 33
    [damage_dealt_record] => 6710
    [damage_received_record] => 31073
    [kills_record] => 50
    [smackdowns_record] => 45
    [headshots_all_time] => 4299
    [nutshots_all_time] => 1925
    [kills_all_time] => 29362
    [deaths_all_time] => 16491
    …
```

Now to get `kills_all_time` just do this:

```
// Return the 'kills_all_time'.
echo $all_stats_json_decoded['kills_all_time'];
```

Which gives us:

> 29362

Comment: I am on safari but I don't see the list of pages that are in the screenshot in the debugger. How did you get there exactly?